# get 1sr N lines from a file of size 4GB python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I want to load first N lines from a very large file (around 4GB). N could be large by itself. I tried to split the large file into chunks and read the chunks one by one. N can be very large such that Number of lines can be greater than a single file chunk. I wrote this code. This is working fine if number of lines can be loaded to a file chunk

```
with open(self.outfile,'rb',self.chunk_size) as input_file
    head=[input_file.next() for x in xrange(N)]
    with open(self.rotatefile,'wb', self.chunk_size) as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(head)
```

What should be done in order process large values of "N"

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is there a good reason for reading the N first rows at once? Can't you read them line-by-line? What kind of processing do you do to them later?

Comment: What kind of file are you reading? Text or binary? You are reading binary now.

Comment: text ... but what difference would it make if its a .txt file or a binary file performance wise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice()` to limit an iterable to a number of items, including limiting a file object to a number of lines. Because you are reading *lines*, you should be opening the file in text mode instead (drop the `b`):

```
from itertools import islice

with open('largefilename', 'r') as largefile:
    for line in islice(largefile, N):
        # Process the first N lines, one by one
        output_file.write(line)
```

This allows you to process the lines *one at a time*, but you'll only process the first `N` lines.

If all you are doing is copying those lines to another file, do:

```
with open('largefilename', 'r') as largefile:
    output_file.writelines(islice(largefile, N))
```

The `file.writelines()` method takes the `islice()` generator and will take 1000 lines at a time to write those in as a chunk to the output file, all in C code.

Comment: @RickyA: The OP should *not* be opening the file in binary mode if he wants to read text lines.

Comment: that is true, but cant really tell from his question what kind of file he has. Lets ask.

Comment: @RickyA Its simply a text file